# SSRS 2005 Report Functions

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, page-lifecycle

In SSRS 2005 (and 2008 I would imagine) you can provide functions to the reports, and if I'm not mistaken, whole assemblies as well, which allow you to perform some type of work before the report is rendered.

Does anyone know at what point in the ASP.NET page life-cycle is this function compiled and / or executed?

I would tend to think it's executed On_Render, but that's obviously just a guess.

Does anyone have any insight, and does a SSRS 2008 Report same functionality, and if so, at what point that that execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom code and report assemblies are compiled in the life-cycle of the report and not necessarily in the life-cycle of your page.

That means, in the usual asynchronous and remote processing case, it happens on the report server, after your page is rendered and sent to the browser.

From peeking with Reflector, I'd guess when not using asynchronous processing, it is happening during PreRender.

If your custom report assemblies need more than Execute permission, be sure to deploy them with appropriate permissions on the report server or, if processing locally, to call the AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain method.